# Target root element with class or data selector within a nested SCSS structure

Tags: css, sass

I have a simple SCSS structure like the following:

```
nav.main {
    a.close {
        svg {
            fill: black;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm then wanting to change the fill property to black if the data theme attribute on `nav.main` is set to `light`.

I'm a big fan of nesting and keeping things 'compact' so ideally I'd want to do something like the below, but unfortunately through all my different combinations I can't work out if it's possible. Ideally I'd prefer not to have to type out `a.close` and `svg` and use the nesting.

I come up against this all the time and always have break out of the nest.

```
nav.main {
    a.close {
        svg {
            fill: black;
            @at-root [data-theme="light"]#{&} {
                // nav.main[data-theme="light"] a.close svg
                fill: white;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oof, that `@at-root` line is hard to read.

You could try this:

```
a.close svg{
    nav.main &{
        fill: white;
    }
    nav.main[data-theme="light"] &{
        fill: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciated response but I'd prefer to keep it parent > child nested if it's even possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a mixin, and pass the theme as an argument? I don't believe there's a way to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

If you use an html element in the selector your SCSS pattern won't work. BUT if you remove it then it should work fine. The problem is that your compiled css isn't `nav.main[data-theme="light"] a.close svg` but `[data-theme="light"]nav.main a.close svg`.

I tried to explain that here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73160384/2159402